# How to write Amount<Issued<Currency>> parameter field in Corda?

Tags: java, kotlin, corda

I am trying to make a CorDapp that uses Amount and am passing "$999" and it does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

> start QXFlow client: "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB",supplier:
>   "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US",dueDate: "2018-01-22T09:12:43.083Z",seller:
>   "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US",buyer:
>   "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB",businessContractAmount: $999,tradingAmount:
>   $400
>
> net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState ->
>   data(net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState) -> com.quanaxy.QX ->
>   businessContractAmount(net.corda.core.contracts.Amount>)
>   -> net.corda.core.contracts.Amount>
>   -> token(net.corda.core.contracts.Issued) -> Found object of type class java.util.Currency in a property expecting
>   net.corda.core.contracts.Issued

Answer (score 0):

Passing $999 would not make for an integer if your code is expecting one. Try adding the input without the $ sign.

Is the type a string where you remove the $ and then turn it into an int? Sounds like extra work.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the quotes around "$999". For example, you can run the `CashIssueFlow` from the node shell as follows:

```
flow start CashIssueFlow amount: $1000, issuerBankPartyRef: 1234, notary: "O=Controller, L=London, C=GB"
```